# install packages in Pycharm

Tags: python, package, pycharm

I installed PyCharm Community Edition 3.0 on windows 7 machine; and tried to install some common packages, like numpy, scipy...

I followed exactly the instruction from the JetBrains website
http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

but the installation always fails...

"Install packages failed: Error occurred when installing package numpy...."

```
  Running setup.py egg_info for package numpy
    Forcing DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Comment: Do you have any additional details?

Comment: Downloading/unpacking numpy
  Running setup.py egg_info for package numpy
    Forcing DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

Comment: You need to add that into a part of the original question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot install `numpy` and `scipy` like this. Depending on your build and Python version, install it [from here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue trying to install numpy 1.9.2 for python 3.4 (most recent version at 02/04/2015)
I managed to fix this by downloading the .exe from http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.2/numpy-1.9.2-win32-superpack-python3.4.exe/download
and now I can use Numpy in pycharm

Hope this helps!

I'm also using Windows 10 TP so I'm guessing this should work on Win7/8/8.1 aswel

Answer (score 0):

For about 3 years, I have been using PyCharm as my Python IDE of choice. It is weird, and annoying, but often true, that you will frequently be unable to use PyCharm to install many packages. This has happened enough times with me that I just stopped using PyCharm to install packages. With a Mac, I install packages using MacPorts. With Windows 7, I download packages from the Unofficial Windows Binary site mentioned above by Games Brainiac.

Answer (score 0):

Download executable file of numpy from http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.2/numpy-1.9.2-win32-superpack-python3.4.exe/download

It works for Window 7 also.

Thanks Rausta

Answer (score 0):

If you created an virtual environment to work in you still can install like "normal" with pip:

```
lsvirtualenv # check that a virtual environment exists

my_project_folder_VE="/home/${USER}/.virtualenvs" 
my_project="TDD"
cd ${my_project_folder_VE}

source ${my_project}/bin/activate
lssitepackages # check for installed packages

pip install requests numpy pandas
```

PyCharm will right away update the projects index and you can

```
import pandas as pd
```