# Issues with scipy installation on Windows - missing blas and lapack

Tags: python, windows, scipy, lapack, blas

I'm trying to install scipy on Windows and got some issues. When running the setup.py file inside the scipy folder (which I cloned from github), I
got an error message saying "NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources
found"

Does anyone know how I could get lapack and blas installed and where I should store these in my computer?

Below is the error message:

[scipy error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkqRP.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should have a look at the Anaconda Python distribution for Windows. It will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: similar questions have been asked on SO (try out the search tool, top rigth). if you don't like anaconda/conda, you can go for http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19369046

= There's a site with many packages already compiled for Windows.  Download the right file for the package from that site and pip install  should work just fine.  Note that the "right file" means it must match the version of python you're using.  The version number for a package is in the file name:  it's the numbers after "cp".  ex:  file name = `pandas-0.17.1-cp35-none-win32.whl` is a package for python version 3.5 since the filename has `...cp35...` in it.